# Flutter local_auth package: number of failed attempts to login

Tags: flutter, biometrics, localauthentication

I am using `local_auth` package in Flutter, where i am using mostly finger print as a biometric way to authenticate and login. I noticed `local_auth` has a built-in mechanism of only 5 wrong attempts to login. After fifth failed try - we have to use our pin.

Is it possible to configure the amount of attempt in scope of that package? E.g. I need only 3 attempts.